# Accessing Variable as a file instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to refer to a variable that is a long string as a example.txt file 
I was wondering how I would go about doing this using Javascript.
Since I cant save the variable as a .txt file, I was wondering if there was some way using javascript to refer to the variable which is a string as a .txt file.

Comment: look at `data://` url schema. It'll help if I got your question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Blob and objectUrl

```
//cross browser
window.URL = (
    window.URL ||
    window.webkitURL ||
    window.mozURL ||
    window.msURL
);

var example = new Blob([variable], {type: 'text/plain'}),
    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(example);
```

then basically you can refer to this variable using url or write this url to anchor and download it

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<a id="captislink" href="'+ url +'" download="example.txt">Save</a>';
```